# Google Maps VBnet

Tags: .net, google-maps

I am trying to get the "travel distance" from one place to another via google maps. The google APIs aren't exactly useful for vbnet.

So I went for another method... i.e. using webbrowser.

http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=XXX&saddr=YYY
this would get the map in the browser and all i thought i could do is to extract the DocumentText to retrieve the information i need but i faced the same problem as
[how to get a full html source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740095/how-to-get-a-full-html-source)

Appreciate any help if there's a way to get the "full source". Or if there are any ways of getting "travel distances" directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process you are talking about is not an *officially supported* way to get travel distance via google maps.  What I would suggest is to use the [Google Distance Matrix API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) which can provide what you are looking for.